# Is it possible to get a statechange of the zoom or other zoom-related parameters in order to dynamically set tickInterval in Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, zooming

edit: fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/o9sjyxqf/ `.`

As I have continued working on a Highcharts project, this question arose.

It is about the tick marks on the xAxis.

I have a Highchart that has daily data points for a certain timeframe (e.g. 6 months). So when the chart displays 6 months, I have roughly 6x30 data points. When zooming in, there will be less, e.g. 3 weeks (3x21 data points).

When viewing without zoom, there is too many data points and the tick marks on the xAxis are cluttered. Reducing the tickInterval unclutters this. But then there isn't enough tick marks on the xAxis when zooming in.

I would like to register programmatically (an event?) when the zoom is being used, ideally also what exactly is being zoomed to, so that the tickInterval can be set accordingly (dynamically, higher value tickInterval for zoomed out, lower value tickInterval for zoomed in).

Is this possible? Is there an event or something similar that registers use of the zoom? What other suggestions do you have to keep the xAxis marks nice and tidy for both zoom in and zoom out, if tickInterval cannot be changed dynamically in dependancy from the zoom?

To demonstrate:
When loading the chart (start and end points are set / zoomed in):
[image: zoomed in 2]

When zooming out:

[image: Zoomed out]

Thanks for your help and support!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `setExtremes` event callback function and update tick interval based on `min` and `max` values.

```
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        events: {
            setExtremes: function(e) {
                const interval = (e.max - e.min) / 6;

                this.update({
                    tickInterval: interval
                }, false);
            }
        }
    }
```

You can also consider using `minTickInterval` or `tickPixelInterval`.

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/d1Lbj9xh/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.events.setExtremes

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.minTickInterval

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickPixelInterval

Comment: This is helpful information and would meet my requirements, if it wasn't for one detail, I perhaps forgot to mention. I'm forced to use categories (https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.categories) in my xAxis instead of the 'datetime'-type. This is because my data only provides calendar weeks, out of which I need to calculate the exact dates, before setting those dates as data points on my xAxis.
So, is it possible to achieve this kind of dynamic tickInterval during different zoom stages while using xAxis-categories?

Comment: Hi @BananaJoe, Sure, we will figure something out, but please update my example with your settings.

Comment: Please excuse my late answer @ppotaczek. You'll find a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/o9sjyxqf/
Now, when zoomed out, the labels are okay. When zooming in, though, the labels could be more frequent. For example, when zooming into a time frame of 2 weeks or so. I will also update the original question with another screenshot.

Comment: Thanks for the example! My code seems to work fine if you round the calculated interval. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/nc5gb27u/

Comment: Looks great so far, we're getting there! One last thing: When zooming in now, the Button to Zoom back out does not get displayed. How can I get that back?

Comment: That is related with the tick interval update. We need to use `afterSetExtremes` event. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ak9vc5Lq/